# C memory deallocation of array stored data structures

Tags: c, memory, realloc, ansi-c

I am writing a C based library and I'm a little confused when it comes to using `free()` to deallocate blocks of memory...
Essentially I have several similar structs defined this way:

```
typedef struct
{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    void     *data;
    size_t stacksize = NULL;
} thread_info;
```

Where I essentially use `realloc()` to allocate memory for this structure and have an array point to it.

My question is, if I use:

```
free(my_array[thread_index]);
```

Would the `free()` call deallocate memory used not just by the structure but all its data types within it, ie. the *thread_id*, *attr*, *data*, and *stacksize* will be deallocated as well or do I have to deallocate them individually then deallocate the structure from the array.

To me it would make sense that if I am using `free()` on such a structure all data contained within it will be deallocated and I wouldn't have to explicitly deallocate each struct attribute but I just want to make sure if that is the case.

Comment: Is `my_array` of type `thread_info[]` or `thread_info*`?

Comment: thread_info *registry = NULL;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dynamically allocated "structures" (i.e. heirarchies of array's, struct's, etc), you need to call free on each pointer from "the bottom up". You can think of this operation as performing a depth-first traversal of a tree.

The usual restrictions apply to variables that are pointers to memory on the stack, rather than the heap. For example, variables defined with `type[n]`, `char[n] = 'abc'`, etc vs. allocations from the heap using the `*alloc` family of functions. Also beware of cases where there are multiple pointers to the same address, calling `free` twice on these is a programming error (though not necessarily a segmentation fault).

Comment: Order matters because if you free a pointer to an address of more allocated memory, that allocated memory will no longer be accessible (unless you have another pointer to it). Essentially, if you have a `void** foo` that you've allocated with `malloc()` (etc), you have to `free(**foo)` before you `free(*foo)`.

Comment: @DanatheSane I deleted question after it pop up in my head suddenly with the obvious answer, then i saw your answer, so the question again for readers ** why order matters **?

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitly deallocate the resources inside your struct, then you can deallocate the struct itself. If you only deallocate the struct, the resources inside will not be deallocated and you will leak them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `free()` all explicitely allocated data with `malloc()`. Every call to `malloc()` virtually mirrored with a call to `free()`.

Basically, you could define a `constructor()` function which allocate the structure and the data inside the strucutre, and `destructor()` function which deallocate it. This could be something like the following code snippet:

```
int32_t         constructor(thread_info **t)
{
  if (NULL == (*t = malloc(sizeof (thread_info)))) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (NULL == ((*t)->data = malloc(sizeof (__data__)))) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}

int32_t         destructor(thread_info *t)
{
  if (free(t->data)) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (free(t)) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```